# Securing .NET application with keys

Tags: .net, licensing, license-key

I am at the point where I need to add keys to my app. What are some of the possible solutions you guys used? I've looked at an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118031/best-activation-key-software-for-net-application) so far, anything else before I decide. My 2 influential factors are:

1. Price
2. Ease of use

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about software protection, take a minute to reconsider it.

Protection schemes are mostly a waste of time. If .NET is similar in this regard to Java, decompiling the code and removing any kind of protection is trivial. The only more or less robust solutions are network based- and these can be very annoying because you are introducing a new point of failure to your application- what happens if your authentication server is down or they lose internet connectivity?

I know that "The Powers That Be" like this stuff, but please, analyze the situation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

[Aladdin](http://www.aladdin.com/)

[Aladdin's Software and Hardware Solution Comparison Chart](http://www.aladdin.com/hasp/protection-keys-benefits-models.aspx)

We purchase these keys and they are very easy to use with sample code generated for you from their utility.  Added to this is they are a very professional company (no I don't work for them but have used their products in 2 different companies)

The basic hardware keys themselves cost around $30per in small qty but you must purchase the "Master" set which is more expensive (at this time I can't recall the cost).